# Spark - How to do computation on N partitions and then write to 1 file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to do a computation on many partitions, to benefit from the parallelism, and then write my results to a single file, probably a parquet file. The workflow I tried in PySpark 1.6.0 was something like:

```python
data_df = sqlContext.read.load('my_parquet_file')
mapped_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_df.map(lambda row: changeRow(row)), ['c1', 'c2'])
coalesced_df = mapped_df.coalesce(1)
coalesced_df.write.parquet('new_parquet_file')
```

but it appears from looking at Spark's web UI that all of the work, including the `map` part is happening on a single thread.

Is there a way to tweak this so that the `map` happens on many partitions while the `write` happens only on 1? The only thing I've tried that I think worked was by putting a `mapped_df.count()` between the `map` and the `coalesce`, but that doesn't feel like a satisfying way of doing it.

Comment: Why do you need the write operation to use only one thread? This can cause OOM error on some cases, and is very inefficient. Also, to help your map operation, maybe calling `data_df.repartition(N)` solves the problem. If it works, please let me know so I can write it as an answer.

Comment: I want to only write one parquet file, regardless of number of threads used to do that. The trick is to do the 'map' on many partitions, which it would already be doing except that when the 'coalesce' is there, in an attempt to only write one output file, the whole pipeline appears to be done on only one thread. The same code without the coalesce uses many threads and writes many part parquet files.

Comment: The main idea around using parquet files is to create many distributed files so it can be written and read in parallel. If you want to write only one file, maybe you could consider saving your data to a text file.

Comment: You can probably cache and RDD before calling count() to materialise it in memory. And only that doing a coalesce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use "repartition(1)" instead of "coalesce(1)".  The issue is that "repartition" will happily do shuffling to accomplish its ends, while "coalesce" will not.

"Coalesce" is much more efficient than "repartition", but has to be used carefully, or parallelism will end up being severely constrained as you have experienced.  All the partitions "coalesce" merges into a particular result partition have to reside on the same node.  The "coalesce(1)" call demands a single result partition, so all partitions of "mapped_df" need to reside on a single node.  To make that true, Spark shoehorns "mapped_df" into a single partition.

Comment: But I dont really understand, so coalesce is only more efficient if all data to be processed can be done on 1 node? Meaning a small dataset? When should I use coalesce since it appears it limits parallelism which is not good for big data processing in general

Answer (score 2):

Spark does lazy evaluation meaning that it won't execute anything until there is a call to an action. `write` and `count` are both actions that *will* tricker execution. Functions like `map` and `filter` are simple being executed *while* doing some action - not *before* doing some action.

Now, your pipeline is extremely simple and you have only one action (`write`), so the `map` is being performed *while writing the file*. With the call to `coalesce(1)` you have, however, also told Spark to gather all data into one partition before performing the `write` action, and since `map` is part of what's being performed in the `write` action, `map` will also run in one partition.

I hope this makes sense. I suggest you also have a read through some of the blog posts on how Spark works. [This one](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/) from Cloudera, should give you some insight :)